# Trying to issue command to a locked VBA workbook

Tags: excel, vba, locked

I have a locked VBA workbook. which I dont want to unlock and want to use as it is.

Through that macro we can fetch data by based on keyword.

When we need to fetch data by using  more than one key word, we have to do it manually one by one and have to wait till the completion of process of one keyword and have to mention other keywords manually one by one to fetch data.

I have written a VBA to give command to locked workbook that after completion of process of 1st keyword VBA will copy 2nd keyword from other sheet cell of new workbook and paste in that locked macro and continue to do so in loop.

Here , my problem is that locked macro gives a message after completion of process of 1st keyword and then we have to click ok on message to continue the loop which I have written.

I don't want locked VBA to pop up message box which processing my request.

Comment: You should unlock it in the VBA, let the macro run, then lock it again - all from within VBA code. Why are you so opposed to having it be unlocked, even for just a brief while?

Answer (score 0):

Buddy actually that macro was prepared by some IT person in my company. Now that IT person has left my company.

we don't know password of VBA. I have to break password of VBA workbook to make changes. Which I don't want to do as our IT team is not in favour of this they are asking to use that macro as it is..